# Android - set text/javascript in web view

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I would like to display the below script in web view:

```
<div id="hello_43211234" class="ym"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">(function(e,t){if(t._ym===void 0){t._ym="";var m=e.createElement("script");
m.type="text/javascript",m.async=!0,m.src="//static.yieldmo.com/ym.min.js",(e.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]||e.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]).appendChild(m)}else t._ym instanceof String||void 0===t._ym.chkPls||t._ym.chkPls()})(document,window);
</script>
```

I tried to place the script in html - inside the body

```
<html>
<body>
     Script
</body>
</html>
```

I am adding the web view as a footer to the list(To note I tried to add a textview as footer and I was able to see the text view):

```
  WebView web;
        LayoutInflater inflaterOf = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        LinearLayout listFooterView = (LinearLayout)inflaterOf.inflate(com.philly.prosportsframework.R.layout.list_with_footer, null);
        web = (WebView)listFooterView.findViewById(R.id.webview_footer);
        web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        //wv.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true); 
        web.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/my_page.html");

        list.addFooterView(listFooterView);
```

Layout for web view:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <WebView  
        android:id="@+id/webview_footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate what exactly the problem is you are having? Or what you are trying to do in the first place? It looks to me like the only thing the javascript does is add another javascript to the page.

Comment: Webview is not displayed. I am not able to see the script in web view

Comment: Well what do you expect to be displayed? Did you write the javascript? What are you trying to do?

Comment: this is the script which needs to be displayed.. <div id="hello_43211234" class="ym"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">(function(e,t){if(t._ym===void 0){t._ym="";var m=e.createElement("script");
m.type="text/javascript",m.async=!0,m.src="//static.yieldmo.com/ym.min.js",(e.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]||e.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]).appendChild(m)}else t._ym instanceof String||void 0===t._ym.chkPls||t._ym.chkPls()})(document,window);
</script>

Comment: Yes you already posted the script, but what do you expect to happen? What are you trying to achieve with this script? And did you write it yourself?

Comment: It is an ad which needs to be displayed with this script

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48595/discussion-between-xaver-kapeller-and-sweety-bertilla)